# Simple Magento Module: Update layout not working

Tags: magento

## The story

I searched for a solution for this, but none of what I can find seems to fix the problem; I'm new to making Magento Modules, and as a start I'm trying to create a very simple change of the title attribute.

## The problem

Is simple: It doesn't work (The Title attribute simply isn't changed). I refreshed all caches and verified that the module is indeed loaded in Config > Advanced > Advanced.

## Code:

*/app/etc/modules/Acme_NewCoolModule.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Acme_NewCoolModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Acme_NewCoolModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/Acme/NewCoolModule/etc/config.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Acme_NewCoolModule>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Acme_NewCoolModule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Acme_NewCoolModule>
                    <file>acme_newcoolmodule.xml</file>
                </Acme_NewCoolModule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

*app/design/base/default/layout/acme_newcoolmodule.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle"><string>Hello World</string></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `Acme_NewCoolModule.xml` codes contain wrong configuration

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Acme_NewCoolModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Acme_NewCoolModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

You had `</Firtal_EnhancedEcommerce>` and `<Firtal_NewCoolModule>`  in it and it is wrong.

I assume your `namespace` is `Acme` and Module name is `NewCoolModule`

Comment: Sorry - I just forgot to change it from the original, it is actually written as you wrote it here. Changed it in the OP now.

Comment: @Dencker : after edit also, your Acme_NewCoolModule is wrong.  Check the closing node `</Acme_EnhancedEcommerce>`

Comment: Thanks for notifying :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code at `/app/etc/modules/Acme_NewCoolModule.xml` should be

`/app/etc/modules/Acme_Newcoolmodule.xml`

**CODE:**

1) Instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Firtal_NewCoolModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Firtal_EnhancedEcommerce>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Firtal_Newcoolmodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Firtal_Newcoolmodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

2) instead of `app/code/local/Acme/NewCoolModule/etc/config.xml`

Should be

`app/code/local/Acme/Newcoolmodule/etc/config.xml`

and the config code should be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Acme_Newcoolmodule>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Acme_Newcoolmodule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <newcoolmodule>
                    <file>newcoolmodule.xml</file>
                </newcoolmodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

where **Acme - Namespace** and  **Newcoolmodule - Module Name**

*Brief on Magento Camel Case Usage:*

You have a config-node in your config.xml called `global/models/yourpackage` in which you save your Prefix for your class models.

When you call `Mage::getModel('packagename/classname')` Magento fetches this config node e.g. `Company_Yourmodule_Models` adds a `_` and then the classname with uppercase first letter:

`Company_Yourmodule_Models_Classname`

if you have `cAMElcaSe` classnames, it is the same way. So let's say your class' name is ClassName then you have to call `Mage::getModel('packagename/className')` and magento resolves it to: `Company_Yourmodule_Models_ClassName`

Comment: Ah, is camel case the problem?

Comment: @Dencker See my edited answer. Paste the above configuration code and check

Comment: Tried it all now, assuming Acme_Newcoolmodule in the first codeblock as well. Still doesn't work. I'm working on a production server (yes I know, I'm a bad boy), so maybe some other module is overwriting the title. Is it possible to do an equivalent to CSS's !important in the Magento Markup?

Comment: Put layout `acme_newcoolmodule.xml` in your design and not in base folder. Also check your layout update in config.xml

Comment: Moved it, refreshed caches; still not working though.